# Forecasting currencies with ARIMA (error occurred: 'ts' object must have one or more observations)

Tags: r

Hi I tried to plot future values with ARIMA but this error happened: 'ts' object must have one or more observations.

Import dataset:
`library(priceR)`
`a <- historical_exchange_rates("THB", to = "USD",start_date = "2010-01-01", end_date = "2021-12-31")`

Making a timeseries dataset:
`library(forecast)`
`a.dfts <- ts(a$one_THB_equivalent_to_x_USD, frequency=12, start=c(2010,01,01), end=c(2021,12,31))`

Apply ARIMA model:
`library(TSA)`
`loga <- diff(log(a.dfts))`
`finala.arma <- arima(loga, order = c(0,0,2))`

Forecasting future values:
`forca.ARIMA <- forecast(finala.arma, h=24, level=c(80,95))`

Then this is where I got an error.
Error in ts(x) : 'ts' object must have one or more observations

Comment: The immediate problem: you have a daily time series, but you are trying to use `ts` to convert it to a monthly series. Lots of data are removed. For `ts`, arguments `start` and `end` can at most be vectors of 2 elements. You are giving them vectors of 3 elements. I think you really want a daily time series, and fit an ARIMA(p, d, q)(P, D, Q)[12] model.

Comment: I had tried to import daily information instead of monthly but still found the same issue. Do you have any suggestions apart from this?

Comment: I haven't done series time series modelling for a long time. I remembered that even ARIMA(p, d, q)(P, D, Q)[12] requires monthly data. The issue is that daily data has no good period for months/quarters: different months have different number of days.

Comment: One bad solution is, we aggregate daily series to monthly series first, by taking average within month. Then your code will work. The other good solution, I don't know if it is feasible using time series methods, is to deal with daily series directly. The best R package for this should be **zoo** and **xts**. But I am not a wizard in this field. Why not ask this same question, plus my comments, on [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com)? There are lots of statisticians there. You will get feedback on what method is proper.